# Where can I find information about SharePoint Foundation 2010 Search?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search, documentation

Lectori Salutem,

I am looking for detailed information about SharePoint Foundation 2010 Search. A simple Google or Bing search does not provide me with sufficient / reliable information.

Can anyone please point me to information sources so I can look-up the following question:

- Does SharePoint Foundation 2010 Search crawl the content of files? In other words, is it possible to search for the content of PDF, doc, txt files?

Thank you in advance.

---

After a very long while of searching, I managed to find some useful information contained in the following links:

- [Technical diagrams (SharePoint Foundation 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806874%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [Search Technologies for SharePoint 2010 Products](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=167732)

Comment: On a related note, you can install Microsoft Search Server Express on top of SharePoint Foundation and get an improved search experience while using SharePoint Foundation.

http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/en/us/search-server-express.aspx

Comment: @JamesGrizzle: Is Microsoft Search Server Express a free product? Will it conflict with my currently installed SharePoint installation or should I install it on a separate server?

Comment: Yes Search Server Express is a free product. You will find sources that say you cannot install them together.  I think otherwise and suggest trying this on a dev environment.

http://sharepointony.info/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=16

The instructions for the iFilter seem incomplete to me on that previous link.  See here for the rest of the instructions (if they are applicable, I'm honestly not sure which iFilter steps are applicable in Search Server Express)
http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2010/06/14/adobe-pdf-ifilter-indexing-with-sharepoint%C2%A02010/

Comment: @JamesGrizzle: Thank you for your suggestions. I'm going to test Search Server Express on a SharePoint 2010 Foundation virtual Machine. Seems to be very promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good introductory video for search (SP Foundation) can be seen here.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee518667.aspx

For your specific queries, SP does index the contents of any file that it has an iFilter installed for.  Adobe is a slightly different case, so these links should also assist.

iFilters: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405170%28v=office.14%29.aspx

MS KB article on stalling Adobe PDF iFIlter: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2293357

Comment: Thank you for your reply Steven. The video you posted is for SharePoint Server. I'm looking for information regarding SharePoint Foundation.

Comment: Nothing about it in the Foundation section (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee263910).  The iFilter links will still be relevant for your query though; I'd suggest browsing them too.